# Why some users don't experience the updates after deploying in AWS ElasticBeanstalk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, web-deployment

I deployed a Node.js app(Actually, React application wrapped by Node.js/Express) to AWS Elasticbeanstalk, and I confirmed that the deployment was successful.
But after deployment, some of the testers could see the updates, but others couldn't.

For me, I was able to see the updates in IE (Internet Explorer) but not in Chrome and Firefox.
I did the hard refresh several times, but there was no luck.
Just using a VPN in another country helped me to see the updates.

Is it something related to the codebase or AWS configuration?
And what is the solution?

P.S. I have never experienced this in the staging environment, and it happened in the production environment.

Comment: Are you using CloudFront? Edge cached content might explain your symptoms.

Comment: Yeah, I use CloudFront. and `x-cache` is set to `Miss from cloudfront`

Answer (score 1):

Short term - invalidate your the cache in CloudFront, wait for it to finish (10-20 minutes) then tell your testers to hard-refresh. Everyone should now see the latest version.

Longer term - Youve hit this problem due to your caching strategy take a look at the headers. I would suggest very short cache times for your main html file - few seconds to a minute etc - that will smooth out the load if you get a lot of simultaneous requests but will propagate any changes fairly quickly. Any assets loaded can use long cache times safely if you reference them in a way that includes the version (eg `/assets.v1.js` or `/assets.js?v=1`).

Comment: 1. I don't think I use cache in CloudFront. `x-cache` is set to `Miss from cloudfront` 2. It's a react application where I don't import those bundle files manually.

Comment: The `Miss from cloudfront` confirms your traffic is routed through cloudfront (so each edge server will obey any caching directives received). If you repeat the request does that header change to a `Hit`? Are you and your testers in the same location or distributed?  (2. google "cache busting in react" - its definitely possible)